# What is the strange occurrence in the combat simulator?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-citadel

There is an achievement in Mass Effect 3 : Citadel called Technical Issues:
[image: technical issues achievement]

What is the strange occurrence in the combat simulator and how do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get to the combat simulator, you need [to beat the main story of the DLC](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/mass-effect-3/achievement/76981-Technical-Issues.html).

> After completion, you will be sent an email with a complimentary pass
>   to compete in the simulator. When you have read the email, proceed to
>   the Armax Arena and talk to the hologram up the stairs and to the
>   left. When you are finished talking to the hologram, head down the
>   stairs, in the center of the room, with a barrier, that says,
>   'Athletes Only', to a terminal where you can set your options and
>   begin combat missions in the simulator.

From there, you will get various requests after completing some matches, and it is the "Unusual Scores" request that leads to discovering the strange occurrence, and thus getting the achievement.

Comment: The requests just ask you to win a match with the settings set in a particular way (enemy type, difficulty, and arena). You'll get the requests via e-mail. You might have to play a match or two before you get the first request, I can't recall for sure.

Comment: @Vaishali You get them by email on the simulator terminal down the stairs. You need to pick the envelope option in the lower right corner, under the simulation main settings.